# Get every nth element of nested lists using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Here's a function that will take a nested ArrayList `allLists`, an index `nth`, and return the nth element of every sublist.

E.g. for `allLists =  {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}`, `nth = 1`, the function will return `{2,5,8}`

```
public static String[] getEveryNthElement(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allLists, int nth) {
        String[] nthList = new String[allLists.size()];
        int n = 0;
        for (ArrayList<String> sList: allLists) {
            if (nth <= sList.size()) {
                nthList[n] = (sList.get(nth));
            }
            n += 1;
        }
        return nthList;
    }
```

I've managed to get a version working where I can print it out:

```
group.stream()
    .forEach(items -> {
        System.out.println(items.get(1));  // prints 2, 5, 8
});
```

How to gather the results into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```java
public static String[] getEveryNthElement(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allLists, int nth) {
    return allLists.stream()
            .map(list -> list.get(nth))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()
    ).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to do a `collect(Collectors.toList())` when you want an array. Just call `toArray(String[]::new)` directly on the stream, `return allLists.stream() .map(list -> list.get(nth)) .toArray(String[]::new);`